# symfony1.x functional testing: access different applications

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I need to provide functional tests for a symfony 1.4 application. I've got 3 applications. Frontend (index.php) is empty and I do not test it. I want to test `api` and `backend` applications.

The default code for a functional test looks like the following:

```
$browser->
  get('/incomes/index')->

  with('request')->begin()->
    isParameter('module', 'incomes')->
    isParameter('action', 'index')->
  end()->

  with('response')->begin()->
    isStatusCode(200)->
    checkElement('body', '!/This is a temporary page/')->
  end()
;
```

The problem is that it seems to access the default application (`frontend`). What can I do to access another application? I've tried things like:

```
$browser->
  get('/api.php/incomes/index')->
```

but all failed. I couldn't find any info about this in the [official docs](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/15-Unit-and-Functional-Testing#chapter_15_functional_tests)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you stated, I can see from `test/bootstrap/functional.php` that the application you try to test in your php file is *guessed* from its filepath.

So my guess is that your test file should be in a repertory with the name of your application. In other words, your test filepath should be in

`test/functional/your_app/your_test_file`